# Panel incorrectly showing repeatedly

Tags: java

This program is supposed to accept 10 single digit numbers and then output the largest number entered.  The program runs fine with the exception that I get the output screen after each number entered. The output is correct. I cannot figure out how to get the output screen to display only after all 10 have been entered.

```
package largest;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Largest {

// Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare variables
    int largest = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int number = 0;

    // Condition statement to repeat loop until 10 digits are entered
    while (counter < 10) {
        // Prompt user for input
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter a number between 0 and 9: ");

        // Try-Catch statements to check and handle format errors
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            number = -1; // Triggers the error message
        }

        // Checks to make sure number is a single digit 
        if (number >= 0 && number < 10) {
            // Determines if the number entered is the largest
            if (number > largest) {
                largest = number;

            }
            // Increases counter variable by 1 with a valid entry
            counter++;
        }
        // Display error message
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Your entry was not a single digit, please re-enter.",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        // Display the largest number
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The largest number entered is: " + largest, "Results",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Move the statement that displays the largest number outside of your while loop (in other words, move that last statement down a few lines).

Comment: Aren't I the idiot tonite. Cannot believe I did not see that. Much thanks @sbat!

Comment: Please create slightly more descriptive question titles and avoid walls of code; you should provide the minimum amount that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `JOptionPane` statement that shows the largest number entered out of the `while` loop

```
while (){
    // code...
}

// Display the largest number
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "The largest number entered is: " + largest, "Results",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mauren. I am brain dead tonite, should have seen that.

Comment: Some ice cream and some sleep might help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't evaluate your output each time.

```
//First get all ten numbers:
int[] numbers = new int[10]; //array of int to store 10 numbers
int counter=0;
while(counter<10){
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter a number between 0 and 9: ");

        // Try-Catch statements to check and handle format errors
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            number = -1; // Triggers the error message
        }

        // Checks to make sure number is a single digit 
        if (number >= 0 && number < 10) {
            numbers[counter]=number;
            counter++;
        }
        // Display error message
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Your entry was not a single digit, please re-enter.",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
}

//Now After that loop evaluate your largers number
int max = 0;     
while(counter <10)
{
if(numbers[counter] > max )
{
max == numbers
}
counter++;
}

// Display the largest number
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The largest number entered is: " + max , "Results",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```